# ¿Cómo renderizar databinding de AngularJS en jQuery onClick function?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Mi problema está en este `onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})`. Cuando trato de renderizar los *bindings* utilizando `onclick` simplemente no sucede nada. Cuando lo hago con `ng-click` se renderizan a la perfección, pero el script de jQuery no se ejecuta con `ng-click`. Pueden verlo en detalle en este [código en plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/m1R1PesR0HoblSaN6M1T?p=preview). Al utilizar `onclick="startTimer(0,5)"`todo funciona bien pero al querer dar los argumento con *databindings* de AngularJS los datos no se renderizan. ¿Alguna idea de cómo resolver el problema?

Comment: Bienvenido a *"SO en Español"*. La pregunta se entiende perfectamente, con mejor nivel de español que otras que se ven por aquí hechas por gente que lo habla toda su vida. Espero que disfrutes de esta comunidad.

Comment: Gracias, hago mi mejor esfuerzo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es que no puedes combinar las funciones de javascript y angular implícitamente:

```js
onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})"
```

Esto no te va a funcionar nunca porque el navegador lo interpreta como un string, por eso es que solo te funciona el `ng-click`

La solucion que veo es que uses ng-click, porque va ser la unica forma que recuperes las variables del `ng-repeat`

Reemplaza esto

```html
<div class="claimButton claimActive">
    <a href="{{ product.url }}" target="_blank" 
       onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})">CLAIM</a>
</div>
```

por esto

```html
<div class="claimButton claimActive">
    <a href="{{ product.url }}" target="_blank" 
       ng-click="startTimer($index,$product.time)">CLAIM</a>
</div>
```

y agrega esta funcion en tu controlador

```js
$scope.startTimer = function(id, time) {
    $("#" + id).next("div").removeClass("claimActive");
    $("#" + id).next("div").addClass("claimWait");
    $("#" + id).removeClass("timerActive");
    $("#" + id).addClass("timerWait");
    $("#" + id).next("div").children("a").text("WAIT");
    if (time <= 60) {
        if (time < 10) $("#" + id).children("#m").text("0" + time);
        else $("#" + id).children("#m").text(time);
        $("#" + id).children("#s").text("30");
    } else {
        if (time < 600) $("#" + id).children("#h").text("0" + time / 60);
        else $("#" + id).children("#h").text(time / 60);
        $("#" + id).children("#m").text("00");
        $("#" + id).children("#s").text("30");
    }
}
```

Te dejo un [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/oZ5P7N7HhxUqaSwvi2K4?p=preview)

Comment: Esto era lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias a ti, pero ahora tengo este error `NaN:00:30` en el contador,  creo que es porque en el controlador no esta la otra parte del jQuery Script `function checkTimers()...` , ¿Como puedo agregar estar parte que hace falta en el controlador?

Comment: Ya corregí el error, había una mala escritura en el databinding `$product.time` la escritura correcta es `product.time`, ¡Merci Beaucoup!

Comment: Perfecto @Johan , si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla :)